# Destruir modal bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

No he encontrado la forma de destruir los modal , actualmente solo los oculto por lo que conlleva que tenga que limpiar manualmente los campos de los modal, he probado lo siguiente sin resultados:

```
$('#Modal').modal('hide');
$('#Modal').removeData();
$('#Modal').data('modal', null);
```

El .remove() cierra el modal pero , hace que la pantalla se ponga en negro y no me permite hacer ninguna acción.

```
$('#Modal').remove();//provoca un bug
```

Ademas estoy usando jquery 2.02 saludos gracias !

Comment: $.remove('#Modal');  no realiza ninguna acción :/

Comment: **¿a que te refieres con destruir modal?**, a lo que yo entienda los modales no se destruyen, por otro lado **¿tienes un formulario dentro del modal?**

Comment: tengo un formulario dentro del modal, cual seria la mejor forma de limpiarlo ?, ya que me mencionas que no se pueden destruir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los modales según en la documentación no se pueden destruir porque no cuenta con un método para ello.

Ya que haces mención sobre limpiar los campos, aquí lo mejor es resetear el formulario con:

```
$('#idForm')[0].reset()
```

o bien:

```
$('#miFormulario').trigger("reset");
```

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
//Limpiando form al ocultar el modal
$('.bs-example-modal-sm').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $('#foma1')[0].reset()
})

//Limpiando form usando un boton
$('#limpio').on('click', function() {
  $('#miFormulario').trigger("reset");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Small modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm">Small modal</button>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form id="foma1">
          <input type="text" />
        </form>
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id='limpio' type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Limpiar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```